# Resize image to the size of JLabel taken dynamically from file chooser in Swing app

Tags: java, image, swing, file, resize

I am uploading images dynamically via file chooser but the image doesn't fit the size of the `JLabel`. How to resolve it?

```
public void image()
{

       fileChooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("."));
fileChooser.setFileFilter(new javax.swing.filechooser.FileFilter() {
                @Override
                    public boolean accept(File f) {
      return f.getName().toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")|| f.isDirectory();                       
                    }
                @Override
                    public String getDescription() {
                        return "JPG Images";
                    }
                });
                int r = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(new JFrame());
                ImageIcon ico=new ImageIcon(fileChooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath());
                UpImage.setIcon(ico);
                file = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();

        try {
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    Logger.getLogger(EntryEmp.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
}
```

Comment: You have a catch 22 problem.  The size of label is, in part, determine by the icon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Grab hold of the image with your `JFileChooser` like below:

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(fileChooser.getSelectedFile());
```

Now calculate the width and height of your JLabel, and send it to the method `resizeImage(BufferedImage image, int width, int height)`. The `resizeImage` method is coded below.

```
// This method resizes the BufferedImage to specified width and height.
// Returns an ImageIcon object.
private ImageIcon resizeImage(BufferedImage image, int width, int height) {

    // image - BufferedImage object of your file selected
    // width - Width of your JLabel
    // height - Height of yout JLabel

    // Creating a temporary Image of your desired size.
    BufferedImage tempImg = new BufferedImage(width, height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D gr = tempImg.createGraphics();

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, width, height, null); // Draw the selected image on the tempImage from co-ordinates (0, 0) to (width, height) of the tempImage.
    g.dispose();  // Clear resources.

    return new ImageIcon(tempImage);
}
```

That's it. Now all you have to do is:

```
label.setIcon(image);
```

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

`ImageIcon scaledImageIcon = new ImageIcon(icon.getImage().getScaledInstance(width, height, java.awt.Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));`

Comment: [The Perils of Image.getScaledInstance()](https://today.java.net/article/2007/03/30/perils-imagegetscaledinstance)

Answer (score 0):

> but the image doesn't fit the size of the jlabel.

You can use Darryl's [Stretch Icon](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/stretch-icon/).

You can have the image automatically scaled to fill the space available to the label. Or you can use proportional scaling to keep the image in its original x/y ratio.